# Altering the URLs from RSS feed using PHP

Tags: php, rss

I just tried something real simple to have an RSS feed send me to the mobile version of the site instead of the full version, but i guess it really isn't this simple.

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents("http://svenskafans.com/rss/site/7.aspx");  
$content = str_replace("wwww", "mobile", $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

That's what i wrote, naively thinking it would just alter all URLs in the RSS feed but sadly it only display the original feed through the echo.

Comment: Do you realise that there are 4 `wwww`'s in that replace? Also, even if it does replace it, your `mobile.svenskafans...` urls give 404s, so it wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: Well, that's just... doh..

Comment: And just to correct another misstake, it should be using "mobil" instead of "mobile". Thanks Steve!